# How to integrate SEO and ensure the performance in Portal Architecture Design?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture, portal

I need to develop a Portal for B2C from scratch, right now I faced two problem:
1.How can I integrate SEO into the architecture design ?
2.How to design the architecture to ensure the performance ?
I need to revamp a website like this :http://www.airasia.com/bd/en/home.html
And why all the enterprise level website are using   *.html ? but not a jsp or asp ? what technology do they use ?
I need to get more knowledge on this field to better finish my job, can someone point me a direction ?
Thanks !

Comment: Sorry, but judging from your questions, you are not really equipped for a project like this yet, and a question on SO won't remedy that. What you're asking for is knowledge that takes months, sometimes years, to accumulate.

Comment: To Pekka, If you are expertise on this field, could you give me some useful reference on this topic ?

Comment: The questions that you have asked as fundamanetal beginners web developers/designers questions. None of your questions are enterprise related. I would suggest you take heed of Pekka's comments and start learning the basics.

Comment: @Memory the site you are linking to has a flight booking engine. An online check-in. An online shop. A log-in area for customers... That functionality is a lot of work for a five-person team or more. Anyway, as Laykes says, you are looking for the fundamentals of web development. I can't recommend anything in the ASP field, but there are certainly good basic literature and learning resources to be found.

Comment: Actually, I am not looking for the basic information, I am looking for some information that I can do it better, these function is not hard, but how can it be finished better ? How to improve the user experience while we are designing the architecture ?

Comment: performance and search engine ranking ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I have a post for [developers considering SEO in their web application](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/07/developers-guide-to-search-engine.html) that can help you on your SEO.

2) For *you* I would suggest **ASP.NET web forms** since it is well equipped for beginners (as well as advanced enterprise level sites). Here is a [get started guide to ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/get-started) to help you out. It allows you to use routing in ASP.NET 4 to make nice URLs and URL rewriting if on an IIS server. For now though if you are not too confident, I *really* wouldn't worry about that.

Anyone more advanced passing by I would recommend  **ASP.NET MVC** by the way. It is a tough concept to crack but well worth it. Unit testing is easier, speed of development is great, stateless. Lovely.

Caveat - Other than touching old school JSP for a bit, my experience is mainly Microsoft so cannot say that the ASP way is THE way. Just a good way.

Comment: thanks down voter. be interested to know why you deemed my answer unhelpful?!

Answer (score 0):

That might actually be a static page, at least the version I saw had nearly nothing 'dynamic' on it that javascript could do easily. Static serves very quickly and scales beautifully.

As for jsp vs asp vs rails vs django, they can all be configured to not require cluttering URLs with file extensions.

If you focus on high-quality data in your application that is easily parsed by simple tools, search engines will find you. Use text for text (text in images is useless), no flash or silverlight or java applets. If your site is useful on your phone, it'll be great for search engines.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this covers the full extent of that site. They have a full-fledged flight booking engine. Web check-in. An online store.

Comment: Then could you give me some reference or book on how to develop such a site ?
To Pekka, If you are expertise on this field, could you give me some useful reference on this topic ?

Comment: @pekka, agreed, the rest of the site sure looks dynamic, but the specific page MemoryLeak mentioned appears static after a superficial look. I'd rather serve static pages where I could to reduce server load.

Answer (score 0):

I found some useful resources on this topic :
http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/
And a useful plugin yslow for performance improvement.
Book: High Performance Web Sites